# ajax jquery form validation always validating false

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I am trying to create a special ZIP code validation based on database values. Therefore I am checking the values by ajax:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validate_country_from", function(value, element) 
{
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax.php",
      data: "action=validate_countryzip&direction=1&zip=" + 
         escape(document.getElementById("zip_from").value) + "&country=" + 
         escape(document.getElementById("country_from").value),
      async: false
   }).done(function(msg)
   {
      if(msg == "true")
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   });
}, addressError);
```

And I am assigning the function in the rules by these rules:

```
zip_from: {
   required: true,
   validate_country_from: true
},
country_from: {
   required: true,
   validate_country_from: true
},
```

The ajax request is working fine, and it is done synchronous, the returned value is also correct but still my validation is telling me that there is an error on the two fields.

I hope someone can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer, but I found the reason: my "done" function is returning a value to the ajax request action, not to the validation method (anonymous delegates are great but sometimes really confusing).

A correct version would be something like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validate_country_from", function(value, element) 
{
   var test = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax.php",
      data: "action=validate_countryzip&direction=1&zip=" + 
         escape(document.getElementById("zip_from").value) + "&country=" + 
         escape(document.getElementById("country_from").value),
      async: false
   }).done(function(msg)
   {
   });

   if(test.responseText == "true")
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}, addressError);
```

However, this is not the final solution because it is not catching any errors and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing your jQuery AJAX methods a little bit there.  I've seen `done()` used after `get()` before, but never after `ajax()`.  Try

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validate_country_from", function(value, element) 
{
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax.php",
      data: "action=validate_countryzip&direction=1&zip=" + 
         escape(document.getElementById("zip_from").value) + "&country=" + 
         escape(document.getElementById("country_from").value),
      async: false,
      success: function(msg){
          if(msg == "true")
          {
              return true;
          }
          else
          {
              return false;
          }
      },
      error: function(x, s, e){
          return false;
      }
   });
}, addressError);
```